# jQuery Form submit does not respond on IE10+ only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following codes to submit an action form:

```
var actionForm = $('<form>', {'action': 'index.php', 'method': 'post'}).append($('<input>', {'name': 'action', 'value': 'cancel', 'type': 'hidden'})).append($('<input>', {'name': 'id', 'value': '123', 'type': 'hidden'}));
actionForm.submit();
```

However, this code works on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, but not IE10+. How come?

Using jQuery 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to append the form to body and submit

```
var actionForm = $('<form>', {'action': 'index.php', 'method': 'post'}).append($('<input>', {'name': 'action', 'value': 'cancel', 'type': 'hidden'})).append($('<input>', {'name': 'id', 'value': '123', 'type': 'hidden'}));
actionForm.appendTo('body').submit();
```

Comment: tested & works like charm from IE 8 to 11. Seems IE does not recognize elements that does not exists in DOM...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />
```

Comment: Isn't this set the browser standard and compatibility to IE 10?